# Data from database not displaying on mobile web page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to fetch data from a database and display on a webpage for a mobile web app I am developing. I am  using jQuerymobile 1.4.5 and XAMPP for the test environment . Everything works fine from the data insertion to storing in the database but on submitting the form , the page shows nothing except for sentence, *"Added to a message to Chats"* and no errors are displayed(even with firebug turned on on firefox). This is my code

```
<ul data-role="listview"> 
    <?php if($get_topics !== 0) {foreach((array)$get_topics as $listTopic) { ?>
        <li>Added to a message to Chats<?php echo $listTopic['date']; ?></li>
    <?php } } ?>
</ul>
```

I'd appreciate if anyone can help point me in the right direction.
Thanks

Comment: I think you just forgot to show us "some" of your code ;)

Comment: The issue is most likely that the data is not being read properly from the database.

Comment: @Elon Than: I don't know which code you'll like to see as I think that it isn't practical to display the whole project of more than 19 files on here.

Comment: I think we need the code that should be doing the work that , well.. isn't working

Comment: You're getting the `Added to...` which means that your loop must be working at the very least. My guess is that `$listTopic['date']` is somehow wrong and your PHP configuration is suppressing warnings/errors. Maybe `date` doesn't exist in that array?